# How to add optional OpenGraph tags for Facebook pixel-based catalog?

Tags: facebook, e-commerce, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-pixel

I have a Facebook commerce catalog set up that adds and updates products via pixel. I need to add some optional data fields for the products, i.e. gender. According to [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/#og-tags), the name of the OpenGraph tag for gender is product:gender and its supported values are Female, Male, Unisex. However, adding this tag to the product pages of my website doesn't seem to work. Facebook's [microdata debugger](https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug) is also not capturing it.

I wanted to know what is the correct meta tag syntax for adding the gender property. Currently I have the tag written as follows:

```
<meta property="product:gender" content={get_gender()} />
```

Other OpenGraph tags such as material and color also doesn't seem to be added. Can anyone help me to get this working?

Comment: Have you first of all checked your generated page source, to see whether those meta tags are actually in there, and have the expected values?

Comment: @Cbroe, yes, the generated page source contains all the meta tags that I have provided. The facebook pixel debugger extension also show that the meta tags are being sent as micro data. It's just that the optional data fields are not being added to my catalog.